# Why are the two definitions equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Definition of limit of sequence:

> For any $\varepsilon>0$, for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $N \leq n \implies |x_n-\ell|<\varepsilon$

But in my book the definition is used in the following form:

> For any $\varepsilon>0$, for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $N \leq n \implies |x_n-\ell|<2\varepsilon$

How are the definitions equivalent?

Comment: this equivalence is clearer if one uses a different letter "for every $\eta>0$ blablabla $<2\eta$". Then, to get from one statement to the other simply set $\epsilon=2\eta$, and to go the other direction, let $\eta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. (The crucial point is that we have a universal quantifer "for every/for all/for any". So, if $\eta$ is positive then $\epsilon=2\eta$ is also positive, and conversely, if $\epsilon$ is positive then $\eta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is also positive.)

Comment: wouldn't be $|x_n-L|$ ? for some number $L$

Comment: Another similar question has ${}< \varepsilon$ in one and ${} \le \varepsilon$ in the other.

Comment: Yeah, to be clear, these are definitions of  $x_n\to 0,$ not general convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common reading difficulting early in proofs and definitions.

A definition using a variable can be rewritten to use a different variable. What is confusing about these definitions is that they both use $\epsilon.$

But, as a commenter notes, the second definition can be re-written:

> For any $\eta>0,$ there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq N\implies |x_n-\ell|<2\eta.$

Now if you have your first definition and your second definition, we can prove each one implies the other.

If the first definition is true, let $\eta>0.$ Define $\epsilon=2\eta.$ Then, by the first definition, there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|x_n-\ell|<\epsilon=2\eta.$

Similarly, if you know the second definition is true, and you have $\epsilon>0,$ then let $\eta=\epsilon/2.$

The only thing you need to know is that if $\epsilon>0$ then $\epsilon/2>0,$ and if $\eta>0$ then $2\eta>0.$

Answer (score 2):

This is because $\mathbb R_{>0}$ and $2\mathbb R_{>0}$ are the same set. If you multiply all positive reals by $2$ (or any other positive factor), you still get the set of positive reals. There is a bijection.